# $ 7×7 $ Table ...

Tags: combinations, coloring, combinatorial-proofs

Start with a $7 \times 7$ grid of houses where the center house is white and the other 48 houses are black. At each move, you select any $3 \times 3$ or $5 \times 5$ sub-grid and change the color of all its houses (from white to black and vice versa).

Is it possible to make all the cells of the $7 \times 7$ grid white with some sequence of moves? If not, why not?

My idea is to use coloring method to show is there possible to make the color of third row same with last and first row, but I got nowhere.

Comment: By combining several moves together, what sorts of regions besides 3x3 and 5x5 squares can you make switch colors?

Comment: One not-so-clever way to solve this is to think of the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^{49}$, and think of the $25+9$ squares as vectors. You are asking if there is a sum (with coefficients either $1$ or $0$) of these vectors that yields the vector that is all 0s except a $1$ in the middle. So there is a $49\times35$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$ that you (or a computer) could reduce to see if the system has a solution.